# android webrtc release build failed

Tags: android, webrtc

I have added webrtc as module to my project. When i build release apk, it fails due to this error

```
> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type org.webrtc.Logging is defined multiple times: C:\\Users\\username\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\2d3b493da32fa7896e96213b98fcfde9\\jetified-base_java.jar:org/webrtc/Logging.class,
 
E:\\myfolder\\libwebrtc\\build\\intermediates\\runtime_library_classes_jar\\release\\classes.jar:org/webrtc/Logging.class","sources":[{"file":"C:\\username\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\2d3b493da32fa7896e96213b98fcfde9\\jetified-base_java.jar"}],"tool":"R8"}
```

[image]

added this module to my app build gradle file

```
    implementation project(':libwebrtc')
```

What you suggest to fix, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using the dependency on Maven 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+' ([example](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/webrtc/examples/aarproject/app/build.gradle;l=48;drc=7ab9c51e80476c74276ec7af88075f1b713b8905))?